# Is Bentham really dead?

Tags: one-piece

I know that Bentham sacrificed himself to save Luffy so that he can escape from Impel Down. 
He disguised as Magellan to open the gates for Luffy, but later the real Magellan came and it seems like the two fight each other (not in screen).

My friends believed that he's dead at that fight. But when I read [this](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bentham), it is stated that he's currently become the new queen of Newkama Land.

> Bentham, alias Mr. 2 Bon Kurei, is a former officer agent of Baroque
>   Works and an okama (a Japanese slang term for a transvestite). While
>   he was once an enemy of Luffy's as a part of the Baroque Works, the
>   two became quick friends, leading Bon Kurei to sacrifice himself for
>   Luffy both at Alabasta and later at Impel Down. 
>   ***He is currently the new Queen of Newkama Land.***

So I want to know, is Bentham or Bon Kurei dead or alive after Impel Down arc? If he alive, have he shown in comics ar anime after Impel Down arc?

Comment: @MaskedMan Oops... Didn't read that.

Comment: The purpose of marking duplicates is not to admonish the asker, but to help them find their answer quickly. :)

Comment: @MaskedMan yup, maybe I really need to read more before asking. And you're fast to show me the answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this chapter cover that shows Mr.2 Bon Kurei is alive and is the new Queen of Newkama Land, so most probably he/she survived after Luffy left him in Impel Down. And aside from this I haven't read or seen him in any chapters after the Impel Down arc.

[image]